# changing sys.path in settings.py

Tags: python, django

In a django test project's `settings.py` I recently tried putting this in:

```
try:
    import mymodule
except:
    import sys
    TESTPROJ_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
    PROJ_PARENT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(TESTPROJ_ROOT, '..'))
    sys.path.append(PROJ_PARENT)
```

The purpose was to add a local project path if `mymodule` wasn't installed in the environment. To aid understanding, the directory structure is as follows:

```
base/mymodule
base/test_project/manage.py
base/test_project/test_project/settings.py
```

This worked so long as `mymodule` wasn't in the environment. As soon as `import mymodule` was executed (anywhere in `settings.py`) I got the error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError django.contrib.admin: cannot import name signals`

I have two questions...

a) is there any way to stop this error from happening?

b) is there another 'smart' way to allow `settings.py` to change the path to allow a module to be locally included if it's not in the environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file `my-site.pth` in a directory that is a part of `sys.path`, and include in that file the full path to the directory you want to add.

`my-site.pth`

```
base/mymodule
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html